# My sql code has error

Tags: sql

SQL code:

```
select DeviceUID, LogType
from `DeviceUsage_Table`
where DeviceUID in (select DeviceUID, Max(LogTime) 
                    from `DeviceUsage_Table` 
                    group by DeviceUID);
```

Error:

> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

How do I solve it?

---

I want to use the first select result as new condition.

```
select DeviceUID, Max(LogTime) 
from `DeviceUsage_Table` 
group by DeviceUID
```

This code I can get each `DeviceUID` and its last `LogTime`.

I use the query result to select DeviceUID's LogType when it is at last `LogTime`, so my method is as above.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense whatsoever. Why would you need the WHERE ... IN condition if you are selecting all of the records in the DeviceUsage_Table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sub-query:

```
"SELECT DeviceUID, Max(LogTime) FROM `DeviceUsage_Table` group by DeviceUID"
```

currently returns two columns, DeviceUID and Max(Logtime). This won't work with `DeviceUID in` as following the `in` you need a list. Either a hand-written list: `("A", "B", "C")` or a query that returns just one column.

What was your reasoning for returning Max(LogTime) too? Then I may be able to help more.

Comment: Please select as correct answer if you are happy with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error message is explicit, it's because by the rules of SQL, in order to use the "in" keyword, the following SELECT must return only 1 column. So you might want to do something like : DeviceUID in (SELECT **DeviceUID** FROM ...

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting two columns in the subquery. You should have only one since you are comparing with one column. Try the below query

```
select DeviceUID, LogType from `DeviceUsage_Table`
        where DeviceUID in 
              (SELECT DeviceUID FROM `DeviceUsage_Table` group by DeviceUID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,

```
(SELECT DeviceUID, Max(LogTime) FROM `DeviceUsage_Table` group by DeviceUID)
```

returns two columns, so you can't use it in an `IN` clause. How to solve it depends on what you want with the query.

```
select DeviceUID, LogType
  from `DeviceUsage_Table`
  where DeviceUID in (SELECT DeviceUID FROM `DeviceUsage_Table` group by DeviceUID);
```

would be valid but does not make sense, as it is the same as

```
select DeviceUID, LogType
  from `DeviceUsage_Table`
  where DeviceUID
```